# google script execution time is too much for more than 300 rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with 75 columns.
I use a doGet to create data in the spreadsheet via apps script ...the script is run from my static HTML page form on my computer.

The apps script is deployed as a web app and anyone including anonymous.
The script I use is from crazycoders - 
https://www.crazycodersclub.com/appscript/crud-operation-on-google-spread-sheet-using-google-app-script-html-jquery/

It works fine when there are not too many records..but once it crosses 200 rows of data - the record creation time has gone up from about 2 seconds to 20 seconds.

I then added 900 rows into the spreadsheet to test and when i try to create - the script goes on forever - i stopped it after 4 min.So looks like above 200 rows the efficiency deteriorates drastically

can you please share your thoughts on how you have implemented it especially when the number of rows are pretty large.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `insert_value()` function for that script loops through every row to check if some Id already exists. It performs a `getRange()` call for every single row. This is known to be a slower operation.

---

**The Solution**

We need to modify that script so that it gets the whole column at once, then runs through that column, rather than getting a single row at a time...

This is just one example of the script doing this, but it looks like it happens many times...

```
  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var id1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if(id1==id){
      flag=0;
      var result="Id already exist..";
    } }
```

I've **updated it** to make it *more efficient* by getting the whole column at once:

```
var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
var ids = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr, 1).getValues(); //Get the whole ids column at once

  for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++){ // Now loop through the column to see if id already exists.
    if(ids[i]==id){
      flag=0;
      var result="Id already exists..";
    } 
  }
```

---

This is the **whole updated script**. I **have not tested this code** you should use it with test data and fully test all the features *before implementing with live, important data!*

```
function doGet(e){

  var op = e.parameter.action;

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Your Spread sheet URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


  if(op=="insert")
    return insert_value(e,sheet);

  //Make sure you are sending proper parameters 
  if(op=="read")
    return read_value(e,ss);

  if(op=="update")
    return update_value(e,sheet);

  if(op=="delete")
    return delete_value(e,sheet);



}

//Recieve parameter and pass it to function to handle




function insert_value(request,sheet){


  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var country = request.parameter.name;

  var flag=1;
  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
  var ids = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr, 1).getValues(); //Get the whole ids column at once

  for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++){ // Now loop through the column to see if id already exists.
    if(ids[i]==id){
      flag=0;
      var result="Id already exists..";
    } 
  }

  //add new row with recieved parameter from client
  if(flag==1){
    var d = new Date();
    var currentTime = d.toLocaleString();
    var rowData = sheet.appendRow([currentTime,id,country]);  
    var result="Insertion successful";
  }
  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   
}





function read_value(request,ss){
  var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput()
      data    = {};
  //Note : here sheet is sheet name , don't get confuse with other operation 
  var sheet="Source";

  data.records = readData_(ss, sheet);

  var callback = request.parameters.callback;

  if (callback === undefined) {
    output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
  }
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

  return output;
}


function readData_(ss, sheetname, properties) {

  if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
    properties = getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname);
    properties = properties.map(function(p) { return p.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); });
  }

  var rows = getDataRows_(ss, sheetname),
      data = [];

  for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
    var row     = rows[r],
        record  = {};

    for (var p in properties) {
      record[properties[p]] = row[p];
    }

    data.push(record);

  }
  return data;
}



function getDataRows_(ss, sheetname) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  return sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}


function getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  return sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
}


//update function

function update_value(request,sheet){

  var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var flag=0;
  var country = request.parameter.name;

  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
  var ids = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr, 1).getValues(); //Get the whole ids column at once

  for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++){ // Now loop through the column to see if id already exists.
    if(ids[i]==id){
      sheet.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(country);
      var result="value updated successfully";
      flag=1;
    } 
  }

  if(flag==0)
    var result="id not found";

  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   


}




function delete_value(request,sheet){

  var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var country = request.parameter.name;
  var flag=0;


  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
  var ids = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr, 1).getValues();

  for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++){
    if(ids[i]==id){
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
      var result="value deleted successfully";
      flag=1;
    } 
  }

  if(flag==0)
    var result="id not found";



  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);    
}
```

Comment: Happy to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: the create,update and delete work so awesome and speeded up-I could hardly believe it ....on the same not is the read_value efficient enough ? or is it possible to improve the efficiency - i ask since i just tested with 10,000 records and it took a while -  yes i will mark your answer as accepted solution - hope you will be able to improve the read-value efficiency

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as I get home

Comment: sorry to be a pain - but i was so excited that it updated the 9000th row being fast i did not notice whether it updated correctly-- for some reason it is updating one row minus - so if the row to be updated is 9..data is being updated in row 8 ...

Comment: Alright, so I've updated it to update and delete the correct rows. However, the `read_values()` function is slow because it grabs all the data from the spreadsheet and returns it in a JSON object. The more rows you have the slower it will be, there is not a lot that can be done for it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot - yes changing it to i+1 works- but i did not understand why it does so-<br> My understanding ids[i]==id - means if  ids in row[i] is = id - so the data has been found in row [i] - however  to update +1 is added and not is

Comment: So there are 2 parts to this. The first is the rows (`getRange() `) are numbered starting at 1, but arrays (`getValues() `) are numbered starting at 0. This would normally break things because of how I did it, but because the sheet contains headers it still works in this specific case.

Comment: cant thank you enough :) ..you have been very helpful